# Кнопка перевода сайта с русского на английский

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

Каким образом можно реализовать кнопку переключения языка сайта в виде иконки с буквами «EN», при клике на которую весь сайт «превращался» бы в англоязычный?

Знаю про возможность использования сервиса Google Translate, но думаю, что этот вариант слишком топорный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сайт должен уметь обрабатывать ссылки вида /en/, /bg/, /jp/ и прочее, по умолчанию язык русский. При переходе по ссылке site.com/en/ из базы тянутся переводы текстов на английском языке. Но это серверное решение. Если стоит задача сделать это все только версткой, то можно поизвращаться либо с js, либо с localStorage, тогда переводы будут браться из готовых массивов данных. Либо просто создать папку en и положить в нее сверстанные страницы на английском языке. Может лучше уточните задачу?

Comment: Этого ответа вполне достаточно, для того чтобы понять, что данные кнопки не нужно пытаться делать front-end'у )) Я думал всё попроще, как допустим с увеличением шрифта на странице по клику.

Answer (score 6):

Если делать правильно, нужно использовать сторонние либы для перевода. Т.е. весь текст сайта хранится в "словаре", а когда нажимаешь кнопку - происходит выбор нужного словаря, меняется текст на сайте.

Таких библиотек много, порезерчи. Нужно посидеть и поковыряться.

Вариант два - гугл транслейтор АПИ
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Вариант три (если сайт очень-очень маленький), просто делай дубли страниц с заменой текста.

Если вопрос был про то, как именно реализовать саму кнопку - все просто. Создаешь , две штуки с разными id. После этого JS-ом вешаешь обработчик событий. 
elementButton = document.getElementById(id);

На него вешаешь обработчик -
elementButtom.addEventListener("click", function(){тело функции});

Если делаешь ссылками - вообще никак не надо обрабатывать. Просто кидаешь линки на переведенные страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Сталкивался с таким, вот мой вариант решения:
Использовать теги типа `<en>`, `<ru>` и подобных (ну или `<div class="en">`)
И дать им всем display:none;
А при загрузке страницы выполнить код:

```
var lang = "en"; //Сюда нужно внести текущий выбранный язык... Хоть с 
localStorage, хоть с печенек, хоть с фиг знает, чего

var style = document.createElement("style");//Создаём <style>
style.innerHTML = lang+"{display:block;}";//Делаем видимым нужные теги
document.head.appendChild(style); //И крепим это добро к <head>
```

Теперь все теги нужного языка будут видимыми! =)

Пример использования:

```
<ru>Русский текст</ru><en>English text</en>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос был про то, как именно реализовать саму кнопку - все просто. Создаешь , две штуки с разными **id**. После этого **JS-ом** вешаешь обработчик событий.

`elementButton = document.getElementById(id);`

На него вешаешь обработчик - `elementButtom.addEventListener("click", function(){тело функции});`

Как это сделать

Comment: Ваш ответ заканчивается вопросом или он просто не дописан?